# Good simple C/C++ FTP and SFTP client library recommendation for embedded Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, ftp, sftp

Could anyone recommend FTP / SFTP client C/C++ library for Linux-based embedded system? I know about [Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) library but I need something as simple as possible just to download files from FTP / SFTP servers. Is there any recommendation to look for? Yes, SFTP support is critical. Actually I can even sacrifice multi-threading because I need only one stream at a time. And I'd like it to be able to work through memory buffers but this should be not a problem.

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:
After spent some time with libcurl I decided not to go this way in favor of direct usage of libssh2 for SFTP and reuse proprietary FTP library from different project. libcurl seems too linked to curl command line tool approach. For example try to get remote file size before starting download operation - it was definitely not planned.

But actually another propositions are welcome especially I see no really simple good public C or C++ FTP client library at all. Everything is either very old and not supported or fresh and wet.

Comment: Which one did u end up using?

Comment: Looking for a C or C++ FTP library in 2024 and there still is none. I know FTP is dying, but it's a pretty shock. I assume the FTP protocol is so simple every program adds the code implementation directly into their application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[libssh2](http://www.libssh2.org/) is a great lib for SFTP - and it also happens to be the lib that (lib)curl uses for SFTP.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [libcurl's alternatives page](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html)? A few options there may provide an FTP solution.

I think if you move away from libcurl, you may need to use two different libraries, one for SFTP (which is really just SSH) and one for FTP.

However, if you do not want to do this, perhaps you want to look at compiling libcurl to link against cyaSSL or PolarSSL instead of openssl to make the installation more lightweight. You could also try to compile it with minimal options, as you only need FTP and SFTP support.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Selected solution was slightly customized openssl and libcurl with only FTP and SFTP protocols enabled. Good enough for my case.

Comment: .. but after some time I had to change it to libssh2 for SFTP and custom FTP.

Answer (score 3):

you can use libssh for sftp. I put some code here for you which has Pause/Resume and works on windows. for linux you need to replace local file handling functions. I cannot copy the  entire class because it will exceed this website limit. change username and password and hostname  to proper equivalents of your sftp server:

```
    int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
    {

        //Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");


        pSFTPConnector  sshc = new  SFTPConnector(L".\\", L"127.0.0.1", 22, L"iman", L"iman");  // change the hostname , port , username, password to your sftp server, your credentials

        //FILE *nullfile = fopen("null", "w");  
        //sshc->setLogFile(nullfile);
        sshc->setVerbosity(SSH_LOG_RARE);       // you can change the verbosity as appropriate for you

        int i=  sshc->InitSession();
        i=sshc->ConnectSession();
        i = sshc->InitSFTP();


        //i = sshc->SFTPrename("renamed_myfile.txt", "myfile.txt");  //change these file names
        //i = sshc->Makedir("sftpdir");
        //i = sshc->testUploadFile("myfile2.txt", "1234567890testfile");


        // change these file names to whatever appropriate
        //i = sshc->SFTPget("c:\\testdir\\Got_CAR_HIRE_FINAL_test.jpg", "CAR_HIRE_FINAL_test.jpg", 64*1024 );  
        i = sshc->SFTPget("c:\\testdir\\get_downloaded_CAR_HIRE_FINAL.jpg", "CAR_HIRE_FINAL.jpg", 64 *1024);
        i = sshc->SFTPreget("c:\\testdir\\reget_downloaded_CAR_HIRE_FINAL.jpg", "CAR_HIRE_FINAL.jpg", 64 * 1024);
        i = sshc->SFTPput("c:\\testdir\\CAR_HIRE_FINAL.jpg", "put_CAR_HIRE_FINAL.jpg", 64 * 1024);
        i = sshc->SFTPreput("c:\\testdir\\CAR_HIRE_FINAL.jpg", "reput_CAR_HIRE_FINAL.jpg", 64 * 1024);

        delete sshc;
        return 0;
    }


typedef enum sshconerr{
    E_OK = 1, E_SESSION_ALOC = -1, E_SSH_CONNECT_ERR = -2, E_SFTP_ALLOC = -3, E_INIT_SFTP = -4, E_CREATE_DIR = -5, E_FILEOPEN_WRITE = -6, E_WRITE_ERR = -7
    , E_FILE_CLOSE = -8, E_FILE_OPEN_READ = -9, E_INVALID_PARAMS = -10, E_SFTP_ERR = -11, E_SFTP_READ_ERR = -12, E_SFTP_READBYTES_ERR = -13, E_GET_FILEINF = -14
    , E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND = -15, E_RENAME_ERR = -16, E_MEM_ALLOC = -17, E_LOCAL_FILE_READ = -18, E_LOCAL_FILE_RDWR = -19, E_REMOTEFILE_SEEK = -20
    , E_REMOTE_FILE_OPEN = -21, E_DELETE_ERR = -22, E_RENAME_LOCAL_FILE = -23, E_LOCAL_DELETE_FILE = -24, E_FILEOPEN_RDONLY = -25, E_SFTP_READ_EOF=-26
                        ,E_UNKNOWN=-999 } ESSHERR;


// status of transfers;
typedef enum sftpstat{ ES_DONE=0 , ES_INPROGRESS , ES_FAILED, ES_STARTING, ES_PAUSED, ES_RESUMING, ES_CANCELLED,  ES_NONE  } ESFTPSTAT;

using namespace std;


// statistics about the transfer;
typedef struct transferstatstruct {
    string remote_file_name;
    string local_file_name;
    __int64  total_size;
    __int64  transferred;
    __int64  averagebps;
    long long   seconds_elapsed;
    long long       seconds_remained;
    int percent;
    ESFTPSTAT transferstate;
} TTransStat;


#define E_SESSION_NEW   -1



// these libraries are required
#pragma comment(lib, "ssh.lib")





// this is the main class that does the majority of the work

typedef class CSFTPConnector{

private:

    ssh_session  session;                 // ssh session
    sftp_session sftp;                      // sftp session
    sftp_file file;                         // structure for a remote file
    FILE *localfile;                        // not used in windows but could be local file pointer in UNIX
    FILE *logfile;                          // the file for writing logs, default is set to stderr
    string filename;                        // file name of the transfer;
    string localfilename;                   // file name of local file;
    string      tempfilename;               // a temporaty file name will be used during the transfer which is renamed when transfer is completed.
    ESFTPSTAT transferstatus;               // state of the transfer which has one of the above values (ESFTPSTAT)
    time_t  transferstarttime;              // time of start of the transfer
    wchar_t username[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
    wchar_t password[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
    wchar_t hostname[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];       // hostname of the sftp server
    wchar_t basedir[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];        // this base dir is the directory of public and private key structur ( NOT USED IN THIS VERSION)
    int port;                               //  port of the server;
    int verbosity;                          //  degree of verbosity of libssh
    __int64  filesize;                      //  total number of bytes to be transfered;
    DWORD  local_file_size_hiDWORD;         //  Bill Gates cannot accept the file size without twisting the programmers, so he accepts them in 2 separate words like this
    DWORD  local_file_size_lowDWORD;        //  these 2 DWORDs when connected together comprise a 64 bit file size.
    __int64 lfilesize;                          // local file size
    __int64 rfilesize;                          // remote file size
    __int64 transfered;                         // number of bytes already transfered
    bool pause;                                 // pause flag
    TTransStat stats;                           // statistics of the transfer
    HANDLE  localfilehandle;                    // windows uses handles to manipulate files. this is the handle to local file.

    ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::rwopen_existing_SFTPfile(char *fn);         // open a file on remote ( server ) read/write   for upload
    ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::rdopen_existing_SFTPfile(char *fn);         // open a file on remote ( server ) read only    for download
    ESSHERR createSFTPfile(char *fn);                                   // create a file on server;
    ESSHERR writeSFTPfile(char *block, size_t blocksize);               // write a block of data to the  open remote file
    ESSHERR readSFTPfile(char *block, size_t len, size_t *bytesread);   // read a block of data from the  open remote file
    ESSHERR readSFTPfile(char *block, __int64 len, DWORD *bytesread);
    ESSHERR closeSFTPfile();        // closes the remote file;
    ESSHERR openSFTPfile(char *fn);  // opens the remote file
    ESSHERR getSFTPfileinfo();          // gets information about the remote file


public:
    wstring errstring;      // the string describing last error 
    ESSHERR Err;                // error code of last error
    CSFTPConnector();           // default constructor;
    CSFTPConnector(wchar_t *dir, wchar_t *hn, int hostport, wchar_t *un, wchar_t *pass);  // constructor
    void setVerbosity(int v);       
    int  getVerbosity();
    ESSHERR InitSession();          // must be called befor doing any transfer
    ESSHERR ConnectSession();       // connnects to the  ssh server
    ESSHERR InitSFTP();     // must be called befor doing any transfer
    ESSHERR Makedir(char *newdir);
    ESSHERR testUploadFile(char *fn, char *block);          // do not use this , only for test purposes for myself
    ESSHERR SFTPput(char *lfn, char *rfn, size_t blocksize);            // Upload a file from start
    ESSHERR SFTPreput(char *lfn, char *rfn, size_t blocksize);          // checks for previouse interrupted transfer, then either continues the previouse transfer ( if there was any) or starts a new one (UPLOAD)
    ESSHERR SFTPrename(char *newname, char *oldname);                   // renames a remote file( must be closed)
    ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPdelete(char *remfile);                  // deletes a remote file
    TTransStat getStatus();                                             // gets statistics of the transfer
    ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPget(char *lfn, char *rfn, size_t blocksize);    // Downloads a file from  sftp server
    ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPreget(char *lfn, char *rfn, size_t blocksize);  // checks for previouse interrupted transfer, then either continues the previouse transfer ( if there was any) or starts a new one (DOWNLOAD)
    void    CancelTransfer();
    void    PauseTransfer();
    void    setLogFile(FILE *logf);         // sets the log file, if not set stderr will be used. by default.
    void    CloseLocalFile();
    void    CloseRemoteFile();

    ~CSFTPConnector();




} SFTPConnector, *pSFTPConnector ;





void    CSFTPConnector::CloseLocalFile()
{
    CloseHandle(localfilehandle);
}


void    CSFTPConnector::CloseRemoteFile()
{
    sftp_close(file);
}



void    CSFTPConnector::setLogFile(FILE *logf)
{
    logfile = logf;
}


void    CSFTPConnector::CancelTransfer()
{
    transferstatus = ES_CANCELLED;

}
void    CSFTPConnector::PauseTransfer()
{
    transferstatus = ES_PAUSED;
    pause = true;
}

//----------------------------------------


ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPget(char *lfn, char *rfn, size_t blocksize)
{
    DWORD       result;
    int rc;
    BOOL  bresult;
    DWORD bytesread;
    filesize = 0;
    transfered = 0;

    pause = false;
    transferstatus = ES_NONE;
    char *block;
    struct stat st;
    wchar_t temp[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
    size_t tempsize;
    wstring wlfn;
    int loopcounter = 0;

    localfilename = lfn;

    filename = rfn;

    tempfilename = string(lfn) + ".sftp_temp";
    mbstowcs_s(&tempsize, temp, tempfilename.c_str(), SHORT_BUFF_LEN);

    localfilehandle = CreateFile(temp, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (localfilehandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
        errstring = L"Could not open local file:" + wstring(temp) + L" for read and write";
        Err = E_LOCAL_FILE_RDWR;
        return E_LOCAL_FILE_RDWR;
    }

    lfilesize =0;
    transfered =0;

    block = (char*)malloc(blocksize + 1);
    if (block == NULL) {
        Err = E_MEM_ALLOC;
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
        errstring = L"Could not allocate memory for file block size";
        CloseLocalFile();
        return E_MEM_ALLOC;
    }

    result = rdopen_existing_SFTPfile((char *)rfn);

    if (result == E_OK){
        getSFTPfileinfo();
        filesize = rfilesize;
    }
    else
    {
        Err = E_REMOTE_FILE_OPEN;
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
        errstring = L"Could not open remote file";
        CloseLocalFile();
        delete block;
        return E_REMOTEFILE_SEEK;
    }


    transferstatus = ES_STARTING;

    sftp_file_set_blocking(file);
    transferstarttime = time(NULL);
    transferstatus = ES_INPROGRESS;

    while (transferstatus != ES_FAILED && transferstatus != ES_PAUSED &&  transferstatus != ES_CANCELLED  &&transferstatus != ES_DONE)
    {
        loopcounter++;

        result = readSFTPfile(block, blocksize, (size_t *)&bytesread);
        if (result != E_OK && result!= E_SFTP_READ_EOF )
        {
            errstring = L"Error reading from remote sftp server file.";
            Err = (ESSHERR)result;
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
            CloseRemoteFile();
            CloseLocalFile();
            delete block;
            return (ESSHERR)result;
        }
        if (result == E_SFTP_READ_EOF)  transferstatus = ES_DONE;
        fprintf(logfile, "Read %d bytes from input file. Number of packets: %d , %llu from %llu bytes\n", bytesread, loopcounter, transfered, filesize);

        bresult = WriteFile(localfilehandle, (LPVOID)block, bytesread, &bytesread, NULL);
        if (bytesread < blocksize)
        {
            if (bresult == FALSE)
            {
                errstring = L"Error writing to local file.";
                Err = E_LOCAL_FILE_RDWR;
                transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
                CloseRemoteFile();
                CloseLocalFile();
                delete block;
                return E_LOCAL_FILE_RDWR;
            }
            else if (bytesread == 0)
            {
                errstring = L"Transfer done.";
                Err = E_OK;
                transferstatus = ES_DONE;
                continue;
            }
        }


        Err = E_OK;

        if (pause == true) transferstatus = ES_PAUSED;
        if (bresult == TRUE &&  bytesread == 0)
        {
            // at the end of the file
            transferstatus = ES_DONE;
        }
        Sleep(BLOCKTRANSDELAY);
        if (loopcounter % 331 == 0)Sleep(77 * BLOCKTRANSDELAY);
        if (loopcounter % 3331 == 0)Sleep(777 * BLOCKTRANSDELAY);

    }

    // closing files
    result = closeSFTPfile();
    CloseHandle(localfilehandle);

    Sleep(1000);


    if (transferstatus == ES_DONE)
    {
        wchar_t temp2[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
        mbstowcs_s(&tempsize, temp2, lfn, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);
        bresult = MoveFile(temp, temp2);
        if (bresult != TRUE)
        {
            Err = E_RENAME_LOCAL_FILE;
            errstring = L"Could not rename local file: " + wstring(temp);
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
            delete block;
            return E_RENAME_LOCAL_FILE;
        }
    }

    if (transferstatus == ES_CANCELLED)
    {
        wchar_t temp2[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
        mbstowcs_s(&tempsize, temp2, lfn, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);
        bresult = DeleteFile(temp);
        if (bresult != TRUE)
        {
            Err = E_LOCAL_DELETE_FILE;
            errstring = L"Could not rename local file: " + wstring(temp);
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
            delete block;
            return E_LOCAL_DELETE_FILE;
        }
    }

    delete block;
    return (ESSHERR) result;
}


TTransStat CSFTPConnector::getStatus()
{
    stats.seconds_elapsed = time(NULL) - transferstarttime;
    stats.averagebps = (transfered * 8) / stats.seconds_elapsed;
    if (filesize > 0) {
        stats.percent = (transfered *100)/ filesize;
        stats.seconds_remained = ((filesize - transfered) * 8) / stats.averagebps;
    }
    else
    {
        stats.percent = -1;
        stats.seconds_remained = -1;
    }
    stats.total_size = filesize;
    stats.transferstate = transferstatus;
    stats.remote_file_name = filename;
    stats.local_file_name = localfilename;

    return stats;
}


ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPrename(char *newname, char *oldname)
{

    int rc=sftp_rename(sftp, oldname, newname);
    if (rc !=SSH_OK){
        return E_RENAME_ERR;
    }

    return E_OK;
}



ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPdelete(char *remfile)
{

    int rc = sftp_unlink(sftp,remfile);
    if (rc != SSH_OK){
        return E_DELETE_ERR;
    }

    return E_OK;
}



ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPreput(char *lfn, char *rfn, size_t blocksize)
{
    ESSHERR     result;
    BOOL  bresult;
    DWORD bytesread;
    filesize = 0;
    transfered = 0;

    pause = false;
    transferstatus = ES_NONE;
    char *block;
    struct stat st;
    wchar_t temp[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
    size_t tempsize;
    wstring wlfn;
    int loopcounter = 0;

    localfilename = lfn;
    //wlfn = wstring(lfn);
    //localfile = fopen(lfn, L"r");
    filename = rfn;
    mbstowcs_s(&tempsize, temp, lfn, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);

    //filesize = getFileSize(localfilename);

    /*if(filesize < 0) {
    transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
    Err = E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND;
    return E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND;
    }*/

    localfilehandle = CreateFile(temp, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (localfilehandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
        Err = E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND;
        return E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND;
    }
    local_file_size_lowDWORD = GetFileSize(localfilehandle, &local_file_size_hiDWORD);
    filesize = (local_file_size_hiDWORD * 0x100000000) + local_file_size_lowDWORD;

    if (filesize < 0) {
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
        Err = E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND;
        CloseLocalFile();
        return E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND;
    }

    block = (char*)malloc(blocksize + 1);
    if (block == NULL) {
        Err = E_MEM_ALLOC;
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
        errstring = L"Could not allocate memory for file block size";
        CloseLocalFile();
        return E_MEM_ALLOC;
    }


    tempfilename = string(rfn) + ".sftp_temp";

    result = rwopen_existing_SFTPfile((char *)tempfilename.c_str());
    if (result == E_OK){
        getSFTPfileinfo();
        sftp_seek64(file, rfilesize);
        __int64 tempi64 = rfilesize & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF;
        DWORD dwlow = tempi64;
        tempi64 = (rfilesize & 0x7FFFFFFF00000000);
        tempi64 = tempi64 >> 32;
        long  dwhi = tempi64;
        DWORD dwResult=SetFilePointer(localfilehandle, dwlow,&dwhi , FILE_BEGIN);
        if (dwResult == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER)
        {
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED; Err = result;  return result;
        }
        transferstatus = ES_RESUMING;
        transfered = rfilesize;

    }
    else{
        result = createSFTPfile((char *)tempfilename.c_str());
        transferstatus = ES_STARTING;
        if (result != E_OK)  {
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED; 
            Err = result;
            CloseLocalFile();
            return result;
        }
        }
        sftp_file_set_blocking(file);
        transferstarttime = time(NULL);
        transferstatus = ES_INPROGRESS;

    while (transferstatus != ES_FAILED && transferstatus != ES_PAUSED && transferstatus != ES_DONE)
    {
        loopcounter++;
        bresult = ReadFile(localfilehandle, (LPVOID)block, blocksize, &bytesread, NULL);
        fprintf(logfile, "Read %d bytes from input file. Number of packets: %d , %llu from %llu bytes\n", bytesread, loopcounter, transfered, filesize);
        if (bytesread < blocksize)
        {
            if (bresult == FALSE)
            {
                errstring = L"Error reading from local file.";
                Err = E_LOCAL_FILE_READ;
                transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
                CloseRemoteFile();
                CloseLocalFile();
                return E_LOCAL_FILE_READ;
            }
            else if (bytesread == 0)
            {
                errstring = L"Transfer done.";
                Err = E_OK;
                transferstatus = ES_DONE;
                continue;
            }
        }

        result = writeSFTPfile(block, bytesread);
        if (result != E_OK && bytesread>0 )
        {
            errstring = L"Error transmitting to remote sftp server file.";
            Err = result;
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
            CloseRemoteFile();
            CloseLocalFile();
            return result;
        }


        Err = E_OK;
        //transfered = transfered + bytesread;
        if (pause == true) transferstatus = ES_PAUSED;
        if (bresult == TRUE &&  bytesread == 0)
        {
            // at the end of the file
            transferstatus = ES_DONE;
        }
        Sleep(BLOCKTRANSDELAY);
        if (loopcounter % 331 == 0)Sleep(77 * BLOCKTRANSDELAY);
        if (loopcounter % 3331 == 0)Sleep(777 * BLOCKTRANSDELAY);

    }

    CloseRemoteFile();
    CloseLocalFile();
    Sleep(1000);

    if (transferstatus == ES_CANCELLED)
    {
        result = SFTPdelete((char *)tempfilename.c_str());
        if (bresult != E_OK)
        {
            Err = E_DELETE_ERR;
            errstring = L"Could not delete remote file.";
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
            return E_DELETE_ERR;
        }
    }
    if (transferstatus == ES_DONE) result = SFTPrename(rfn, (char *)tempfilename.c_str());
    delete block;
    return result;
}




ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::getSFTPfileinfo()
{
    sftp_attributes fileinf = sftp_fstat(file);

    if (fileinf == NULL){
        return E_GET_FILEINF;
    }

    rfilesize = fileinf->size;

    sftp_attributes_free(fileinf);
    return E_OK;
}

ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::closeSFTPfile()
{
    int rc = sftp_close(file);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Can't close the written file: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(session));
        return E_FILE_CLOSE;
    }
    return E_OK;
}


ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::writeSFTPfile(char *block, size_t blocksize)
{
    size_t nwritten = sftp_write(file, block, blocksize);
    if (nwritten != blocksize)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Can't write data to file: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(session));
        //sftp_close(file);
        transfered = transfered + nwritten;
        return E_WRITE_ERR;
    }

    transfered = transfered + nwritten;
    return E_OK;
}

ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::readSFTPfile(char *block, size_t len, size_t *bytesread)
{

    DWORD readbytes;
    *bytesread = 0;
    if (len <= 0) return E_INVALID_PARAMS;
    if (bytesread == NULL || block == NULL) return E_INVALID_PARAMS;

    readbytes = sftp_read(file, block, len);
    if (readbytes < 0)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Can't read  from  remote file: %s  %s\n", filename.c_str(), ssh_get_error(session));
        *bytesread = 0;
        return E_SFTP_READ_ERR;
    }


    if (readbytes <  len)
    {
        *bytesread = readbytes;
        transfered = transfered + readbytes;
        return E_SFTP_READ_EOF;
    }


    *bytesread = readbytes;
    transfered = transfered + readbytes;

    return E_OK;

}

ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::readSFTPfile(char *block, __int64 len, DWORD *bytesread)
{
    DWORD readbytes;
    *bytesread = 0;
    if (len <= 0) return E_INVALID_PARAMS;
    if (bytesread == NULL || block == NULL) return E_INVALID_PARAMS;

    readbytes = sftp_read(file, block, len);
    if (readbytes < 0)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Can't read  from  remote file: %s  %s\n", filename.c_str(), ssh_get_error(session));
        *bytesread = 0;
        return E_SFTP_READ_ERR;
    }


    if (readbytes <  len)
    {
        *bytesread = readbytes;
        return E_SFTP_READ_EOF;
    }


    *bytesread = readbytes;
    transfered = transfered + readbytes;

    return E_OK;

}


ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::createSFTPfile(char *fn)
{

    int access_type = O_CREAT | O_RDWR;
    int rc, nwritten;

    filename = string(fn);
    file = sftp_open(sftp, fn,
        access_type, S_IWRITE);
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Can't open file for writing: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(session));
        return E_FILEOPEN_WRITE;
    }
    return E_OK;
}


ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::rdopen_existing_SFTPfile(char *fn)
{

    int access_type = O_RDONLY ;
    int rc, nwritten;

    filename = string(fn);
    file = sftp_open(sftp, fn,
        access_type, S_IREAD);
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Can't open file for writing: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(session));
        return E_FILEOPEN_RDONLY;
    }
    return E_OK;
}




ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::openSFTPfile(char *fn)
{
    int access_type = O_RDONLY;
    int rc, nwritten;

    filename = string(fn);
    file = sftp_open(sftp, fn,
        access_type, S_IWRITE);
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Can't open file for writing: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(session));
        return E_FILE_OPEN_READ;
    }
    return E_OK;

}

ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::Makedir(char *newdir)
{
    int rc;
    rc = sftp_mkdir(sftp, newdir, S_IFDIR);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        if (sftp_get_error(sftp) != SSH_FX_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS)
        {
            fprintf(logfile, "Can't create directory: %s\n",
                ssh_get_error(session));
            return E_CREATE_DIR;
        }
    }

        return E_OK;
}




SFTPConnector::CSFTPConnector()
{
    //libssh2_init(0);
    session = ssh_new();
    if (session == NULL)
    {
        Err = E_SESSION_ALOC;
        errstring = L"Could not allocate a session.";

    }
    wcscpy(hostname, L"localhost" );
    wcscpy(username, L"User");
    wcscpy(password, L"Password");
    wcscpy(basedir, L".\\");
    port = 22;
    verbosity = SSH_LOG_RARE;
    filesize = 0;
    transfered = 0;

    pause = false;
    transferstatus = ES_NONE;
    logfile = stderr;
}


CSFTPConnector::CSFTPConnector(wchar_t *dir, wchar_t *hn, int hostport, wchar_t *un, wchar_t *pass)
{

    session = ssh_new();

    if (session == NULL)
    {
        Err = E_SESSION_ALOC;
        errstring = L"Could not allocate a session.";

    }
    wcscpy(hostname, hn);
    wcscpy(username, un);
    wcscpy(password, pass);
    wcscpy(basedir, dir);
    port = hostport;
    verbosity = SSH_LOG_RARE;
     filesize=0;
     transfered=0;

     pause=false;
     transferstatus = ES_NONE;
     logfile = stderr;

}


ESSHERR  CSFTPConnector::InitSFTP()
{
    int rc;
    sftp= sftp_new(session);
    if (session == NULL)
    {
        Err = E_SFTP_ALLOC;
        errstring = L"Could not allocate a sftp session.";

    }

    rc = sftp_init(sftp);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Error initializing SFTP session: %s.\n",
            sftp_get_error(sftp));
        sftp_free(sftp);
        return E_INIT_SFTP;
    }


    return E_OK;
}


ESSHERR  CSFTPConnector::ConnectSession()
{
    char temp[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
    size_t n_of_chars;
    wcstombs_s(&n_of_chars, temp, SHORT_BUFF_LEN, (const wchar_t *)password, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);
    int ir;

    ir=ssh_connect(session);
    if (ir != SSH_OK){
        errstring = L"Could not connect the ssh session.";
        return E_SSH_CONNECT_ERR;
    }

    ir=ssh_userauth_password(session, NULL, temp);
    if (ir != SSH_OK){
        errstring = L"Could not connect the ssh session.";
        return E_SSH_CONNECT_ERR;
    }
    return E_OK;
}


ESSHERR  CSFTPConnector::InitSession()
{
    char temp[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
    size_t n_of_chars;
    wcstombs_s(&n_of_chars, temp,SHORT_BUFF_LEN, (const wchar_t *) hostname, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);
    ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST,temp);
    ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &verbosity);
    ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);
    wcstombs_s(&n_of_chars, temp, SHORT_BUFF_LEN, (const wchar_t *)username, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);
    ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER,temp);
    wcstombs_s(&n_of_chars, temp, SHORT_BUFF_LEN, (const wchar_t *)basedir, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);
    ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_SSH_DIR, temp);

    return E_OK;
}


CSFTPConnector::~CSFTPConnector()
{


    sftp_free(sftp);
    ssh_disconnect(session);
    ssh_free(session);

    return;
}
```

Comment: This approach (with libssh2) was actually used for SFTP.