# FTP Server strange response when trying to login

Tags: c++, linux, ftp

I have the following code which should log me on a ftp server, the function send_get() simply sends the message from msg to the ftp server and fetches the response. print_resp() prints the response from the server. When I execute this code I get:

```
451 The parameter is incorrect. 

451 The parameter is incorrect. 

500 '

 ': command not understood.

451 The parameter is incorrect. 

500 '

 ': command not understood.
```

Im using test.rebex.net (195.144.107.198) server and it seems to work fine on broswers and other online ftp testers.

```
bool ftp_mirror::login(const char* user, const char* pass){
    strcpy(msg, "CLNT ftp-mirror\n");
    if(!send_get())
        return false;
    print_resp();

    strcpy(msg, "USER ");
    strcat(msg, user);
    strcat(msg, "\n");

    if(!send_get())
        return false;
    print_resp();

    strcpy(msg, "PASS ");
    strcat(msg, pass);
    strcat(msg, "\n");

    if(!send_get())
        return false;
    print_resp();
    return true;
}
```

and these are some other functions i used in my code

```
bool ftp_mirror::send_msg(){
    if(0 > send(msg_sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0)){
        perror("send_msg")
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool ftp_mirror::get_resp(){
    memset(resp, 0, RESP_LENGTH);
    if(0 > recv(msg_sock, resp, RESP_LENGTH, 0)){
        perror("get_resp")
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool ftp_mirror::send_get(){
    if(!send_msg())
        return false;
    if(!get_resp())
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think it's time for you to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). For example, print the *exact* raw data being sent and received (or see it while stepping through the code in a debugger).

Comment: Show some [MCVE]. BTW, code above looks like some C++, not C code. And FTP is a complex protocol, so why don't you use some *existing* library like [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) ?

Answer (score 0):

The FTP protocol uses `CRLF` as its newline sequence. So change

```
strcat(msg, "\n");
```

to

```
strcat(msg, "\r\n");
```

I also recommend using `sprintf()` rather than sequences of `strcpy()` and `strcat()`, e.g.

```
sprintf(msg, "USER %s\r\n", user);
```

Or maybe you should avoid reinventing the wheel, and use an existing library like `libcurl`. If you need something lighter, see [Good simple C/C++ FTP and SFTP client library recommendation for embedded Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919797/good-simple-c-c-ftp-and-sftp-client-library-recommendation-for-embedded-linux)

Comment: I made the changes you suggested now the server processes the first command and asks for USER and PASS but after that it breaks again, and I would like to use a library but this is a school project and I must make it from scratch

Comment: I guess there's some other problem with the command you send after logging in.